# How to search within specific websites at once?

Tags: bookmarks, search-engines

Is there any way to search through specific websites at the same time ??

I mean , if i want to search for a movie, song or whatever

Can I search for it, only through my Bookmarks Using any search engine or an applet ??

Hope to get helpful answers as usual ..Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Google specific website search by adding `site:` option to the search string, for example:

```
The Avengers site:imdb.com
```

That will search within the specified site. Very powerful option.

You can also search within multiple websites, to do that use the operator `OR`:

```
The Avengers site:imdb.com OR site:boxofficemojo.com
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to search many websites at the same time, you can use [Google's Custom Search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70308&topic=1717070&ctx=topic). Using this tool Google will create a custom search tool for you where you define which websites to search and a lot of other things using a control panel. You can use the page provided by Google or you can even embed the search tool within your own website if you wish.

Comment: Ooh! that's a good fast answer HaLaBi ...but unfortunately it's not what I'm Looking for.. your answer my friend isn't the Practical solution if u want to search within tens or maybe hundreds of bookmarked sites!! but thank u very much 4 ur answer, it'll help a lot of people including me .

Comment: @ENG.KARIM I have updated the answer to solve your problem.

Comment: It is exactly what i am looking for..may be better.

-I Really appreciate ur help Halabi...Thaaaaanks

Answer (score 0):

Other than Google Programmable Search Engine and advanced search there are a few more alternatives that are a bit more user-friendly in my opinion.

I've built a tool, called [Bardeen](https://bardeen.ai), that searches multiple sites in separate tabs with a shortcut. It's free and can be launched from anywhere on your computer.

In general, searching websites requires

1. understanding website link structure
2. adding a query to the URL
3. launch the URL with the query in a separate tab

Here is an article on how to do this with a video:
https://www.bardeen.ai/posts/how-to-search-multiple-websites-at-once

There is also [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-multi-search/aamgapdgopfdmokckpkfciiddpahbbcg?hl=en) that I found, but it hasn't been updated since 2015. May work for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting tool. But the original poster states they want to search for items from multiple websites that are sourced from their browser bookmarks. Like if they have hundreds of bookmarks, use a tool to specifically search across those hundreds of bookmarked sites. Can your tool do that?

Comment: So the process would be to grab bookmarks websites and then add those as a Google advance search query?

I haven't built functionality to access bookmarks yet, so it'd not be "dynamic" when new book marks are added. Very unique use case. 

It can be done though. Let me look into it.